# What is the correct terminology for this circulant & symmetric matrix with only two distinct elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, circulant-matrices

Is there a special terminology to describe a matrix of the following form in $\mathbb{C}^{4\times 4}$ or more generally $\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$?

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & b & b \\ 
b & a & b & b \\ 
b & b & a & b \\
b & b & b & a
\end{bmatrix}$

I initially wanted to refer to such matrices as symmetric and circulant, however, there are symmetric and circulant matrices that do not have the above form, how could I refer to matrices of the above form?

Comment: This question seems to have been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121971/473276). There have also been numerous questions about [the determinant of this matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86644/473276). Personally I would probably describe it as "a linear combination of the [all-ones matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones) and the identity matrix", which is the key insight in finding its eigenvalues.